# How to place divs with background-images in order with 100% width?

Tags: html, css

Explanation image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/397267/css-problem.jpg

Hello guys,

I need your help.
I would like to put some screenshots on a webpage. The screenshots shall not be displayed bigger than their original size (Picture 01). If they viewport is wider than the pictures original size, the picture should just be centered with no background.

When the viewport is smaller than picture, the picture should just be scaled down by keeping its proportions! (Picture 03)

I tried it that way, but this didn’t work well. *background-size: contain* does a good job resizing my screenshots (height/width), but the div keeps its height (Picture 04), so I need your help how I could fix that?

```
.w01-startseite {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 882px;
min-height: 300px;
background: url(01_startseite.png) no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
background-size: contain;
```

}

Comment: sorry it's unclear from your picture...

Comment: show us your HTML so we can see the issue.

Comment: Is it at all possible to use the HTML `<img>` tag instead of background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
/* HTML sample */
<div class="Screenshot" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/sports/)"></div>

<div class="Screenshot" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/sports/)"></div>

/* CSS */
.Screenshot {
  overflow: hidden;

  margin: 2em auto;
  max-height: 1200px;
  max-width: 1200px;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: contain;
 }

/**
 * 1. Adjust this value to alter the aspect ratio.
 */
.Screenshot:before {
  display: block;

  padding-top: 50%; /* 1 */

  content: "";
 }
```

example: http://codepen.io/defo550/pen/GgMeBp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I can’t integrate my images with <img> because I need them for an hover-effect.

Comment: I added an example to the codepen that shows you how to do it with a background image.

Comment: Unfortunately, the div stills needs a height.

Comment: @horrible-coder I updated the codepen again so that you do not need to set a explicit height for the background-image: http://codepen.io/defo550/pen/GgMeBp